# my Callback in CollectionViewCell doesn't work correctly

Tags: swift, callback, closures, tableview

**I have a simple CollectionViewCell with PhoneNumberTextField and a callback that I want to send to my server**

```
class PhoneNumberCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, NiBLoadable, UITextFieldDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var phoneLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var PhoneNumberTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var SecurityLabel: UILabel!

var returnValue: ((_ value: String) -> ())?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    Decorator.decorate(self)

}

func setPhoneLabelText(text: String) {
    phoneLabel.text = text
}

func setSecurityLabel(text: String) {
    SecurityLabel.text = text
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    returnValue?(PhoneNumberTextField.text ?? "") // Use callback to return data
}
```

}

**and I also have my ViewController with my CollectionView and I cant get my phoneNumber from cell to variable in ViewController. Here is come code**

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let models = model[indexPath.row]

    switch models {
    case .phoneNumber:
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PhoneNumberCollectionViewCell.name, for: indexPath) as? PhoneNumberCollectionViewCell {

            cell.setSecurityLabel(text: "_ALLYOURDATAISINSECUREDAREA")
            cell.setPhoneLabelText(text: "_YOURPHONENUMBER")
            cell.PhoneNumberTextField.text = phoneNumber

            cell.returnValue = { value in
                self.phoneNumber = value
            }
            return cell
        }
```

**and when I print what I got from textField I got nil**

```
   @objc func sendPhoneNumber() {     
    print("PHONE NUMBER IS - \(String(describing: self.phoneNumber))")
}
```

**what's wrong am I doing???**

Comment: Did you set your `textfield` delegation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the delegate for the textField, or the textField delegates wont work.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    Decorator.decorate(self)
    PhoneNumberTextField.delegate = self
}
```

Side note: 
Don't capitalize variables and constants.

Edit to secondary question:
You either want to (through the Xib) make an `IBAction` outlet that is called on value changed, or:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldValueChanged), for: .editingChanged)
```

both options will call the delegate function every time a letter is typed or removed.

Comment: Thanks! but now I got another problem. I should always tap around to call function textFieldDidEndEditing! Do I have any another methods  without this tap??)))

Comment: You mean you have to change target before `textFieldDidEndEditing` triggers?

Comment: Edited the answer for you.

Answer (score -1):

Have you registered your collection view cell and declare the delegate and datasource?

```
 let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

 let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
 collectionView(PhoneNumberCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: PhoneNumberCollectionViewCell.name)
 collectionView.delegate = self
 collectionView.dataSource = self

 return collectionView
```

Comment: It's not relevant to collectionView `datasource`, textfield delegation should be set in `UICollectionViewCell`